# How to transfer a folder with different Jupiter notebooks with project names and versions into a Git project?

Tags: git

I have many similar notebooks in one folder. The problem is the same for all - predicting probability of default of companies. There are several industries, and models are different for each industry. Also, there are many versions for each industry. So I have a folder with many notebooks such as

> retail3.ipynb
>   construction2.ipynb
>   transport5.ipynb
>   transport6.ipynb

etc and other folders, e.g. data. I plan to move this folder to Git project. Is it a right choice? How can I do this? The only option I see is to manually keep only first versions of files, commit, then second versions (without versions in names), commit, and so on. Also, versions are not related to each other, so retail3.ipynb and transport3.ipynb are not related. I use Windows and Jupyter Lab, if it's important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is a reasonable approach, you may want to script it, and preserve edit dates (if that sort of thing is available on your file system or the file format metadata, or some other location)